# What are the metal tabs that are coming out of these usb connectors?

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-3

[image]

For these USB 3 cables - the ones that go from the motherboard 19 pin connector to the front IO of the chassis - I found some online that have these small metal tabs on them.

What are they?

Also many of the listings for these cables contain something about 'fixed feet' - what does that mean?

For example,

"*19Pin/20Pin Female Header to Dual USB 3.0 Front Panel Desktop Motherboard Mount Cable Cord **with Fixed Feet** 60CM*"

"*USB3.0 data cable front chassis panel cable 20 Pin to A female 19 Pin to Type-C **with fixed pin card** board DIY modified chassis*"

Comment: They seem like some kind of mounting for connection to the case?

Comment: yeah, since this cable uses a mobo header, its meant to be installed inside the system case, and the clips help you mount them into the case so you can connect devices to them.

Comment: Possibly even solder points.